# change rails console colors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs, colors, console

I'm using rails console within my emacs and found that it sets the color of strings to black. The problem is my background is also black so to see the text I have to select it with the mouse.

Is there a way to change the color rails console uses for strings?

Here is my .irbrc

```
require 'irbtools'
IRB.conf[:AUTO_INDENT] = true
IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = true
IRB.conf[:LOAD_MODULES] = [] unless IRB.conf.key?(:LOAD_MODULES)
unless IRB.conf[:LOAD_MODULES].include?('irb/completion')
       IRB.conf[:LOAD_MODULES] << 'irb/completion'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you can always move your cursor over the text in Emacs and type:

```
M-x customize-face <enter>
```

That should bring up the customize window where you can change the settings for the font being used ( including font family, background color, foreground color, etc ).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which mode you're using to run the rails console, but it's very possible that the color translation from the terminal codes output by irb to the Emacs faces in use is being done by ansi-color.el.

If so, take a look at ansi-color-names-vector, which lets you set the mapping between the terminal color escape sequences and the Emacs faces used.  You'd change the first element of this vector to display the terminal's idea of "black" in some other color, for e.g.

Also useful is ansi-color-faces-vector, which lets you decide how to display terminal sequences for bold/underline/etc.